# Gradle - Skip test in custom task

Tags: gradle

When running a gradle build from the command I can skip tests like so:

```
./gradlew build -x test
```

I have a custom task that cleans, builds and releases to Maven local defined like so:

```
task releaseLocal(type: GradleBuild) {
    tasks = ['clean', 'build', 'publishToMavenLocal']
}
```

When I call this, neither of the following tasks skip testing:

```
./gradlew releaseLocal
./gradlew releaseLocal -x test
```

What can I add to the task to skip testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tasks of type `GradleBuild` provide a property called `startParameter`. This property is of type [`StartParameter`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/StartParameter.html) and can be used to pass configuration otherwise passed via command line parameters. Task names passed using the `-x` option are stored in the `excludedTaskNames` property, so you may use the following code to exclude the task named `test` from your build:

```
task releaseLocal(type: GradleBuild) {
    tasks = ['clean', 'build', 'publishToMavenLocal']
    startParameter.excludedTaskNames = ['test']
}
```

However, this will exclude the task `test` for every invocation of `releaseLocal`, so you may try to use the following code to pass command line parameters from your current build:

```
task releaseLocal(type: GradleBuild) {
    startParameter = gradle.startParameter.newInstance()
    tasks = ['clean', 'build', 'publishToMavenLocal']
}
```

This should copy the command line parameters from your current build, so now you should be able to skip any task by calling `gradle releaseLocal -x <task>`.

Please note, that you cannot change the order of the two configuration statements in the second example. Internally, the property `tasks` of `GradleBuild` will be applied to its `startParameter` property, so you must define the `tasks` **after** overwriting the `startParameter` property.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a bit late on the party, but you could use `assemble` instead of `build`.
Basically, `build` means `assemble`+`test`

Answer (score -1):

Try these two commands:

```
gradle -q releaseLocal
gradle -q releaseLocal -x test
```